# Calculate Date Months SQL

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

What I am trying to figure out is how to automatically calculate the total of funded dates for the last 4 months up to the current month for every month. For example since it is June I want Feb, March, April and May's funded accounts. This is the codec I have now and can't seem to figure it out.

```
DECLARE @Year int

set @Year = 2013

SELECT  
   d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) February
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December
FROM 
   tdealer a 
JOIN 
   tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
JOIN 
   tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
JOIN 
   tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
WHERE 
   a.dealer_code = '0003594' and YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year
GROUP BY
   d.name,
   a.dealer_code,
   b.last_name,
   b.city, b.state, b.phone
```

Comment: if it was currently Feb, would you want Jan only, or last Oct + Nov + Dec + Jan ?

Comment: What's not working for you?  This code looks fine, are you just not sure how to limit it to the last 4 months?

Comment: What database provider are you using?  Sql Server?  Oracle?  Please explain how the query should work if the previous four months would cross into the previous year.  Why are you using a @Year parameter when you mention the current time.  Should month be passed in as a parameter or retrieved using SYSDATE/GETDATE()?

Comment: I am using MySQL server 2008 R2. Also @GoatCo I want past 4 months of the present month. So right now is June so I want Feb, March, April and May's funded accounts. I want the Date function to automatically know that each time a user inputs the date.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to figure out is how to limit it to the last 4 months (and assuming SQL Server), you can change your `WHERE` criteria to:

```
WHERE a.dealer_code = '0003594' 
  AND YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year
  AND c.Funded_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-4, 0) 
  AND c.Funded_date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't provided too much info or replied to the questions in the comments, here's my best guess:

```
SELECT
   d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone, 
   MONTH(c.FundedDate), 
   COUNT(c.FundedDate) as RecordCount

FROM 
   {... same as existing ...}

WHERE 
   a.dealer_code = '0003594' and YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year
   and MONTH(GETDATE()) - MONTH(c.FundedDate) between 1 and 4

GROUP BY
   d.name,
   a.dealer_code,
   b.last_name,
   b.city, b.state, b.phone,
   MONTH(c.FundedDate)
```

Comment: I agree, however I asked the OP about that (see first comment) but got no answer ... he already has the YEAR matched up in the WHERE clause, if it's good enough for him now I'm not going to argue the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may have syntax error.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth int

SET @CurrentMonth = MONTH(GETDATE())


SELECT  
   d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = @CurrentMonth THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CurrentMonth
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DATEADD(M,1,c.Funded_date)) = @CurrentMonth THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) PrevMonth
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DATEADD(M,2,c.Funded_date)) = @CurrentMonth  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CurrentMonth-2
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(DATEADD(M,3,c.Funded_date)) = @CurrentMonth THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) CurrentMonth-3
FROM 
   tdealer a 
JOIN 
   tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
JOIN 
   tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
JOIN 
   tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
WHERE 
   a.dealer_code = '0003594' and DATEDIFF(M, c.Funded_date, GETDATE()) <= 4
GROUP BY
   d.name,
   a.dealer_code,
   b.last_name,
   b.city, b.state, b.phone
```